# Why is this not working if everything should be correct?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a programme of creating New Users and adding them to a DB.
So, the structure of the data is:

`#data = {'name': name, 'username': username... 'unique_id' = unique_id...}`

So, the problem is in the creation of the data.
It works until a certain point. Look at the start:

```
class NewUser:

    def __init__(self, name: str, username: str, email: str, age: int, sex: str):

        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.non_verified_email = email
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex
    
        print('got data')

        self.finish_data()

    def unique_id(self):
    
        print('get id')

        return users.get_unique_id(self.username)

    def verify_email(self):

        print('email verified')

        return self.non_verified_email

    def adultness(self):
    
        print('inside')

        if self.age >= 18:

            print('adult')
            return True

        else:
            
            print('child')
            return False

    def finish_data(self):

        self.id = self.unique_id()
        self.verified_email = self.verify_email()
        self.adult = self.adultness()

        self.data = {
            'name': self.name,
            'username': self.username,
            'us_id': self.unique_id,
            'email': self.verified_email,
            'age': self.age,
            'adult': self.adult,
            'sex': self.sex
        }

        print(self.data)
        self.add_to_DB()

    def add_to_DB(self):

        print('adding to DB')
        users.add_new_user(self.data)
```

So you can see I made it print a lot of thing right? Well it was just to see were the programme stoped working. You see, the problem is not actually that there is an uncorrect syntax it's that it stopes, and, instead of printing something it just does nothing, it doesn't even stop the program.
So, I tried to erase the adult part(same happend but what it didn't print was the self.data) so I think it may be a problem relation with some background tasks in my program or something.
I add the rest of my program so that it's easier to understand:

```
class UserDB:

    def __init__(self):

        self.users = []

    def add_new_user(self, data):

        self.users.append(data)

    def get_unique_id(self, username):
    
        n = 0
        change = True

        while change:
        
            n += 1

            new_id = '@' + username + str(n)

            for user in self.users:

                for us_id in user.values():

                    if us_id == new_id:

                        change = True
                        break

                    else:

                        return str(new_id)    

users = UserDB()

us1 = ''
us2 = ''
us3 = ''

us = [us1, us2, us3]

for i in range(2):

    us[i] = NewUser(input('name'), input('username'), input('email'), int(input('age')), input('sex'))
```

There may be other errors in the program but i'm interested in solving this one, Thanks for everything! :)

Comment: Can you just give it an oportunity before downvoting, or can you tell me what should I change?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you need to use a debugger. Also read [ask] and [tour].

Comment: I looked the debugger but there is actualy nothing bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's happening in that UserDB.get_unique_id function, but it looks like it could easily loop infinitely. I suggest re-writing it as the following:

```
def get_unique_id(self, username):
    n = 0
    for user in self.users:
        if user.get('username') == username:
            n += 1

    if n == 0:
        return username

    username = f'@{username}{n}'
    return username
```

It has the same idea you tried to implement, and it could be written better, but for the sake of simplicity it's like that. What's happening: you make a variable to count users with the same username (n, from the same code of yours), then you iterate through all users from the database, and each time you find a user with the same username, you add 1 to the count variable. If it's still 0 when the loop finishes, you set their desired unique id as @username, but otherwise it's set to @usernameN, where n is your n variable.

You also made a small mistake in the NewUser.finish_data function, it should pass self.id into self.data's 'us_id' field, instead of a self.unique_id function:

```
self.data = {
        'name': self.name,
        'username': self.username,
        'us_id': self.id,  # instead of self.unique_id, which is a function reference
        'email': self.verified_email,
        'age': self.age,
        'adult': self.adult,
        'sex': self.sex
    }
```

Comment: Okay, it works perfectly, but I think that I'll change a little bit some parts, thanks a lot!